# Is there a way to give outer border in every section of uicollctionview?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

Try to add outer border of every section in a collection view.

If i'm using **cell.layer.border**, it will also create an inner border. Is there a simple way to create outer border only for every section in collection view?

Try to created red border like image below

[image]

Comment: Unclear what you are asking, but it sounds as if you might be describing a Decoration View.

Comment: @matt added an image, how to create the red border

Comment: No straightforward way to do it. However, there are solutions out there. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37478971/uicollectionview-section-border-in-swift and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44455602/set-border-for-sections-in-collectionview

Comment: @ShawnFrank i tried the second link. But my viewforsupplementaryelementofkind is still uicollectionsecfoot and header. 

Should i change the collectionview class to squaremosaiclayout ?

 IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView! -> IBOutlet weak var collectionView: SquareMosaicLayout!

Comment: Your collectionview stays the same as UICollectionView, it's the layout that will change to `SquareMosaicLayout`. However, I don't think you should do that as well as there is a lot of extra code to make the mosaic layout which is not what you need. You need to just use the principle of creating your own custom layout and you need to try and find the code that adds the border to the section. This is what you need.

Comment: So i need to change the layout from flow -> custom and change the layout to squaremosaic ?

If im not usign squaremosaiclayout, how can i go to the **body** part that are not exist in uicollectionview. Because it's only show header and footer @ShawnFrank

Comment: @lauwis - I will create an example for you later today if you still need it

Answer (score 1):

As Matt pointed out in the comments and the articles pointed out, you would need to make use of a DecorationView.

You can read up on this [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout)

So to do this, you would have to follow these steps:

1. Create a custom `UICollectionReusableView` which would serve as your decoration view
2. Subclass `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` to create a custom layout
3. Override `layoutAttributesForDecorationView` and `layoutAttributesForElements` to figure out the frame of each section and place the decoration view in the section frame
4. Use the custom flow layout as the layout of your collection view

Here is that in code

1. Create the Decoration view, which is just a regular view with a border

```
class SectionBackgroundView : UICollectionReusableView {
    
    static let DecorationViewKind = "SectionBackgroundIdentifier"
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        // Customize the settings to what you want
        backgroundColor = .clear
        layer.borderWidth = 5.0
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

2. Create a custom flow layout

```
class BorderedFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        
        // Register your decoration view for the layout
        register(SectionBackgroundView.self,
                 forDecorationViewOfKind: SectionBackgroundView.DecorationViewKind)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func layoutAttributesForDecorationView(ofKind elementKind: String,
                                                    at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        if elementKind == SectionBackgroundView.DecorationViewKind {
            
            guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return nil }
            
            // Initialize a UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes for a DecorationView
            let decorationAttributes
                = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forDecorationViewOfKind: SectionBackgroundView.DecorationViewKind,
                                                   with:indexPath)
            
            // Set it behind other views
            decorationAttributes.zIndex = 2
            
            let numberOfItemsInSection
                = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: indexPath.section)
            
            // Get the first and last item in the section
            let firstItem = layoutAttributesForItem(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: indexPath.section))
            
            let lastItem = layoutAttributesForItem(at: IndexPath(item: (numberOfItemsInSection - 1),
                                                                 section: indexPath.section))
            
            // The difference between the maxY of the last item and
            // the the minY of the first item is the height of the section
            let height = lastItem!.frame.maxY - firstItem!.frame.minY
            
            // Set the frame of the decoration view for the section
            decorationAttributes.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                                                y: firstItem!.frame.minY,
                                                width: collectionView.bounds.width,
                                                height: height)
            
            return decorationAttributes
        }
        
        return nil
    }
    
    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        
        // Get all the UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes for the current view port
        var attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)
        
        // Filter to get all the different sections
        let sectionAttributes
            = attributes?.filter { $0.indexPath.item == 0 } ?? []
        
        // Loop through the different sections
        for sectionAttribute in sectionAttributes {
            
            // Create decoration attributes for the current section
            if let decorationAttributes
                = self.layoutAttributesForDecorationView(ofKind: SectionBackgroundView.DecorationViewKind,
                                                         at: sectionAttribute.indexPath) {
                
                // Add the decoration attributes for a section if it is in the current viewport
                if rect.intersects(decorationAttributes.frame) {
                    attributes?.append(decorationAttributes)
                }
            }
        }
        
        return attributes
    }
}
```

3. Make use of the custom layout in your view controller

```
private func configureCollectionView() {
    
    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero,
                                      collectionViewLayout: createLayout())
    
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
    
    collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self,
                            forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    
    // You can ignore the header and footer views as you probably already did this
    collectionView.register(HeaderFooterView.self,
                            forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader,
                            withReuseIdentifier: HeaderFooterView.identifier)
    
    collectionView.register(HeaderFooterView.self,
                            forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter,
                            withReuseIdentifier: HeaderFooterView.identifier)
    
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    
    view.addSubview(collectionView)
}

private func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    
    let flowLayout = BorderedFlowLayout()
    flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 10
    flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10
    flowLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical
    flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10,
                                           left: horizontalPadding,
                                           bottom: 10,
                                           right: horizontalPadding)
    
    return flowLayout
}
```

Doing all of this should give you what you want

[image: Custom UIViewCollectionView UICollectionViewFlowLayout border around each section decoration view iOS swift]

I have only posted the most important snippets. If for some reason you can't follow along, here is the [full code](https://gist.github.com/shawn-frank/e5f6324f42f2ac1366f502df84945ed7) to recreate the example